# Regex - finding a string that occurs in another string every n (fixed) characters

Tags: python, regex

My question title is probably unclear so i'm going to try explain with a few examples to better explain

I have only just started using regex, and would like to use it to match a string that occurs (hidden) within another string every n characters, for example:

We want to find the world "hello" in this string:

```
"h..e..l..l..o......"
```

Note how it repeats every 2 characters

I was able to create a simple regex rule for this as follows:

```
"h.{2}e.{2}l.{2}l.{2}o"
```

However this only works once every 2 steps, I wanted it any amount of steps (or at least say up to 5) - such that it would also match a string like:

```
"h...e...l...l...o"
```

What I did try:

```
"h.{1,5}e.{1,5}l.{1,5}l.{1,5}o"
```

However this does not fix a number in all the ranges so say this string would pass even though it doesn't appear in fixed intervals:

```
"h..e..l.l..o"
```

Notice the single character between the 2 l's. My only other thought here would be using a loop to say iterate 1 to 5 and try all of these as individual regex statements, but thought would be useful to try asking here to see if there are any neat ways I can do this with regex :)

Thankyou for any responses

Comment: Are the obfuscating characters, in this case ".", always non letter characters? If so, a regular expressions lookahead may be the solution you're after. Here's a [reasonable tutorial on lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: @AaronCiuffo They could be anything a-z, 1-9 etc. In this case I just used them for the simplicity of reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a capture group and back-reference for this:

```
h(\.{1,5})e\1l\1l\1o
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TbS3wB/1)

Here `(\.{1,5})` after first letter `h` will match 1 to 5 dots and capture in group #1. Afterwards we use back-reference #1 i.e. `\1` between each character to make sure we match same number of dots between all letters.

Comment: This looks really promising :) I am having troubles with this myself, trying this out now and `re.search("h(\.{1,5})e\1l\1l\1o", "h..e..l..l..o..")` is returning None

Comment: Use raw mode: `re.search(r"h(.{1,5})e\1l\1l\1o", "h..e..l..l..o..")`

Comment: If you want to match any character in between then use: `r"^h(.{1,5})e\1l\1l\1o\1?$"`

Answer (score 0):

Try `''.join(re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]",text))` if you wish to extract only alphabets from the text and it is one word.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer :) but this is not what I wanted, the dots could be anything like `"Hz1E90Lk,LP.O"`and the idea is to return whether or not the world "HELLO" is hidden in the string seperated by fixed intervals of characters

Comment: Oh understood ! Thank you for clarifying again :P :) I completely missed it.